# Java: How to read available audio tracks in a video file?

Tags: java, video, metadata, media

Some video files contain multiple audio tracks. Multiple languages for example. Is there a library which gets information about these audio tracks? Names of the audio tracks would be sufficient.

It should support common formats (mkv, avi,...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. From Java I call the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mkv
```

Then I read the commands output and filter the lines which start with `Stream #`.

This works on all my files with multiple audio tracks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best monolithic media file library available is that for VLC player. I seem to remember there was a Java wrapper, but it's probably not maintained (like all Java wrappers more than a few weeks old heheh).